# Bootstrap full width search box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to make a full width search box. its working in tab and mobile but not working in desktop or laptop

Here is my code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-10">    
<form action="" autocomplete="off" class="navbar-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input name="searchtext" value="" class="form-control" type="text">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="addressSearch">
                   <span class="icon-search"></span>
               </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

when I see the responsive view its working on mobile and tab view
[image]

But its not working in desktop view
[image]

Comment: Include your CSS so we can help you

Comment: put your input group in <div class = "row"></div>

Comment: @Arvaan I have put full code from `<from...` to `</form>` inside a div with class `row`. so my full code is like `<div class="row"><form>.............</form></div>`.

Comment: @tenderloin I use only `bootstrap.min.css`.

Comment: see the update code @all

Comment: I have checked it. if you remove 'navbar-form' from form. it would work all well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove you nav-bar class and add form-horizontal

```
<form action="" autocomplete="off" class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input name="searchtext" value="" class="form-control" type="text">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="addressSearch">
                   <span class="icon-search"></span>
               </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: It works, but if I use a glyph like `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>` in the `input-group-btn`, it will go at the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Give col-lg-12  class to the div

```
<form action="" autocomplete="off" class="navbar-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div class="input-group col-lg-12">
    <input name="searchtext" style="width:100%" value="" class="form-control" type="text">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="addressSearch">
           <span class="icon-search"></span>
       </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: give col-lg-12 class to div inside your <form>  and to your outer <div>  after row <div>

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
     <div class="form-group">
        <input name="searchtext" value="" class="form-control" type="text">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="addressSearch">
               <span class="icon-search"></span>
           </button>
        </span>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation for your answer.